# Bundling Angular 4 with Visual Studio 2017 and .Net Core 2.0

Tags: angular, bundle

I have created a .Net Core 2.0 project with some Angular 4 modules and components. Now I have seen in Fiddler that every single component (.js file) is purchased separately from the server.

I set Compilation to Release mode to figure out if there is an inbuild bundling.

Is there a way to bundle this? similar to BundleConfig.json in .Net?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to bundle it but it require some additional setup. [This article](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler) is a great start and goes through all the motions that are required to bundle your application. While the compilation part in the guide will require a specific compiler, the rollup library can be changed for other libraries like [browserify](http://browserify.org/).

Once you have gone through all the Angular setup you can then use grunt or gulp to automate the build process. Both grunt and gulp can be integrated in [Visual Studios Task Runner Explorer](https://exceptionnotfound.net/using-gulp-js-and-the-task-runner-explorer-in-asp-net-5/) window so you can compile from Visual Studio and you can setup binding so that your build task also run at compile time.